# Factorials in prime number calculation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers

The factorial of a number $n$, written as $n!$, denotes the product of all integers from $1$ to $n$. For example, $5! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 = 120$.

> Show that if $n$ and $m$ are integers such that $2 \leq m \leq n$, then $n! + m$ is never a prime number (that is, it is a composite number).

So far, I've identified that because $n$ is greater than or equal to $2$ and $m$, that the factors of $n!$ include $n$, $1$, $m$, and $2$, while the factors of $m$ equal $1$, $m$. Thus, $n!$ cannot be prime, but what do I prove next?

Comment: You seem to have $m$ in the lists of factors of $n!$ and of $m$.  This has implications for the factors of $n!+m$.

Comment: @Henry are there certain rules about adding numbers together that make them prime? And are the factors for n!+m not just the same ones as I listed out?

Comment: The factors of $n!$ include $m$. Let $n! = qm$, then $n!+m = \ldots$

Comment: Though $n$ may be $2$, so $n!$ alone can be prime.

Comment: @peterwhy but even with $m=n=2$ you have $n!+m= 2!+2=2\times (1+1)$ here so the sum is not prime.

Comment: @Henry True, my comment was responding to the statement “Thus, $n!$ cannot be prime” in the question.

Answer (score 0):

$m$ is less than $n$ implies that by definition of the factorial $m$ divides $n!$
this implies that $m+n!$ cannot be co-prime to m and therefore cannot be prime or when written into more formal logic $(((m\le n\implies m|n!)\implies \mathrm{gcd}(m,n!+m)>1)\land (m\ge2)) \implies (m+n!)\in\{p\in\mathbb{N}|\nexists(((x,y)\ne(1,1))\in\mathbb{N}^2|p=xy)\}$